# Changing only 1 element of a compound data type

Tags: haskell

I have the data type:

```
data Person  = Person {
    person_id :: Int,
    person_firstname :: String,
    person_surname :: String,
    person_address :: Address
}
```

I would like to change let say the value of `person_firstname` which in haskell means copying everything else. Is there an easier way to do this than:

```
        person'' = Person (person_id person') newName (person_surname person') (person_address person')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Record update:

```
person' = person { person_firstname = newName }
```

Note that it works on any expression:

```
somebody = (Person 0 "Nobody" "Nothingson" "123 Fake St.")
  { person_firstname = "Somebody"
  , person_surname = "Somethingson"
  }
```

The `RecordWildCards` extension can also save you some typing, but I recommend it only for short definitions where the names can’t get away from you:

```
incrementId person@Person{..} = person { person_id = person_id + 1 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing it is by using lenses from the [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.9.1) package:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens

data Person  = Person {
    _person_id :: Int,
    _person_firstname :: String,
    _person_surname :: String,
    _person_address :: String
}

makeLenses ''Person

examplePerson = Person 7 "aaa" "bbb" "ccc"

modifiedPerson = set person_firstname "zzz" examplePerson

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn $ view person_firstname modifiedPerson
```

Lenses have the advantage that they are easily composable; they come in handy when you have nested data structures.